# How do I loop through a menu in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I can loop through html menus with jQuery just like in text fields e.g.

```
$("#table input['type=text']").each(function(){

});
```

How do I do the same for drop down menus?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the selector to match the elements in the `<select>` element, which are `<option>` elements:

```
$("#select option").each(function(){

});
```

Comment: it is not a menu of list but it is an input element i.e <select name="select"  id="select">
        <option value="ewrew">sdfd</option>
        <option value="tfdfdgdf">sfsdf</option>
    </select>

Comment: @John: same answer applies, just a different selector - I've updated it for you.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through your menu items or any element just specify which class or element you want to loop through.

List:

```
$("#menu li").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val()); // Alert demonsatrating option value
});
```

Dropdown's

```
$("#menu option").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val()); // Alert demonsatrating option value
});
```